# My regular expression is not working Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex, express

I have a regular expression which extracts some text to an array. The code works fine in the frontEnd but it doesn't work in the node.js server.

Whenever I run the code in the backend I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
   at C:\Users\PureTech\master\app\server\routes.js:26:11
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express-session\index.js:433:7
   at C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:305:11
```

This is the code I'm talking about. It is a  regular expression that extracts specific numbers in the "text" variable to an array.

```
var text = '[Extracted] id: 194805284, Waxaad $55 ka heshay  MAXAMED  CABDILAAHI JAAMAC SAALAX (252906152669) Tar: 15/04/19 08:44:40, Haraagaagu waa $1,042.7[Extracted] id: 193537533, Waxaad $3 ka heshay  ABDULKADIR  ABDIDAHIR FARAH (907794804) Tar: 14/04/19 10:15:32, Haraagaagu waa $59.17';
var reso = text.replace("$", "");
var textArray = reso.split('[Extracted]');

var regularExpression = new RegExp(/id:\s+([0-9]+).+Waxaad\s+([0-9]+).+[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)\)\s+Tar:\s+([0-9\/\s:]+)/i);
var output = [];
var item;
for(var i = 1; i < textArray.length;  i++){
    item = textArray[i].match(regularExpression);
    output.push({
        id: item[1].trim(),
        amount: item[2].trim(),
        time: item[3].trim(),
        number: item[4].trim()
    });
}

console.log(output);
```

I want this script to work on the backend(node.js) as it works on the frontEnd.

Comment: You don't need `new RegExp()`!  The `/.../` notation is already a regex object ready to use.

Comment: Also when using strings you need to double escape `\\`.

Comment: The second string extracted by the `.split()` does not match the regular expression. The `$` before the `3` is not allowed. The `.replace()` call only gets rid of the *first* `$` in the string, not all of them.

Comment: The problem is that the regex can't get the item[] variable. It displays this error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: @Axmednuur yes and that is because the second time through the loop `.match()` returns `null`.  It does so because the regular expression does not match the second string, because the attempt to remove the `$` characters only removes one of them. It has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much I couldn't see those errors.

Comment: `var reso = text.replace(/\$/g, "")` will replace all of them :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define:

```
var regularExpression = new RegExp("id:\s+([0-9]+).+Waxaad\s+([0-9]+).+[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)\)\s+Tar:\s+([0-9\/\s:]+)", "i");
```

Or

```
var regularExpression = /id:\s+([0-9]+).+Waxaad\s+([0-9]+).+[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)\)\s+Tar:\s+([0-9\/\s:]+)/i;
```

Comment: I tried your answer. It still can't find the item[] object. It displays this error :- TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: @Axmednuur: Because your regex doesn't match your string. For example, `Waxaad\s+([0-9]+)` doesn't match `Waxaad $55`. Before using `item[1]` test if `item` is a non empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

1. I removed all the '$' signs by using this script `var reso = text.split('$').join("");`
2. I removed the new RegExp.

And then it worked fine.